# POWERSHELL extract email and use it

Tags: powershell

Hello I would like to extract the email from user .

I tried to use this code .

$MailManager =Get-ADUser "$manager" -Properties mail |Select-Object mail

but I have this @{mail=cracker@lol.fr} and is not perflectly fine .
I am looking cracker@lol.fr without {} and mail=

because I make a script and is necessary for me to extract only the mail adress without put this information in file  .

I hope you can helping me because I can't find this information .

thank you .

Comment: Use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Mail`

Comment: Thank you so much .
Sorry for duplicate ,I tried with this word extract or export but it was only in file csv .
Have a good night .